# JavaScript + MySQL: use fields as parameter in result

Tags: javascript, mysql

I'm quite new to JavaScript and I have the following issue:
I have a Node.JS server on which a webclient can connect and execute functions. One function is to look into a MySQL database and gather information.

The query is done right and I obtain the correct raw information as for example:
[image]

Here is my code:
[image]

So I correctly get the column names using the fields (fields[0].name = Count_0)variable and I am able to get the correct value using the result (result[0].Count_0 = Gray).

However, I am unable to merge the two lines in order to create the list of colors using something like this in a loop: result[0].fields[0].name = Gray

Is there an easier way to do this or not ?

Thanks,

Nicola.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Javascript, you can use the [] operator to access a variably-named property in an object.

Instead of using `result[0].fields[0].name`, use

```
result[0][fields[0].name]
```

You won't get any runtime errors for accessing a property that doesn't exist, so you'll want to check whether that value is undefined before using it somewhere else.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you want to get the color. If so, you can get the color by this

```
let color = result[0][fields[0].name];
```

The idea is use fields[0].name as key of result[0].

This is the breakdown of above single line.

```
let key = fields[0].name;
let color = result[0][key];
```